# Enum values into string PHP

Tags: php, enums

I am working on a PHP application that is connected to a RESTful webservice which itself is connected to a Database. And in my RESTful I have an Enum that saves the Enum's values as integers in the databse. But when I have to make GET Api in the PHP layer, is there anyway that I can somehow convert, I don't know if that is the right word, the int values into string so that in stead of showing 2 it shows "Single" for example.

This is the Enum I have in the Webservice.

```
public enum BookingType { Single, Group, Tournament }
```

And this the php part.

```
<?php
$uri2 = "http://examdatabasebooking.cloudapp.net/BookingService.svc/getbookings/";
if (isset($_POST["DateAndTimeFrom"])) {
        $FDateAndTimeFrom = $_POST["DateAndTimeFrom"];

$jsondata = file_get_contents($uri2 . $FirstName);
$booking = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
```

Note: In the foreach I just tried something like extracting the BookingType as the value and then setting the value as an array which holds the Enum values, so everytime I GET a booking, depending on the enum value it will write out Single, Group or Tournament.. But it doesn't work..

```
foreach ($booking as $value) {
  $jsondata = $value["BookingType"];
  $value = array("Single" => 0, "Group" => 1, "Tournament" => 2);
}
if(empty($booking)) {
 echo "No bookings!";
else {    
echo $booking["DateAndTimeFrom"] . " " . $booking["DateAndTimeTo"] . " " .     $booking["BookingType"];     
}

}
?>
```

And this is what it prints out: 
DateAndTimeFrom: Oct 5 2016 1:00PM DateAndTimeTo: Oct 5 2016 2:00PM 
BookingType: 2 <= this should print out Tournament in stead of 2

Comment: Or create them as "Backed Cases" -  "have an additional read-only property, value, which is the value specified in the definition." then `$enumCase->value` or `YourEnum::YourCase->value` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare an array for your values.

```
$bookingTypes = array(
    'Single',
    'Group',
    'Tournament'
);
```

And to get the string, with your `$booking['bookingType']`:

```
echo $bookingTypes[$booking['bookingType']]; // Tournament
```

And if you have custom values instead of `0, 1 and 2`:

```
$bookingTypes = array(
    9 => 'Single',
    20 => 'Group',
    54 => 'Tournament'
);
```